# Using mappedRequestHeaders in Spring XD

Tags: spring-xd

I am trying to simulate the following curl statement

curl -k -H "username: Your API Username" -H "password: Your API Password" https://infoconnect1.highwayinfo.govt.nz/ic/jbi/TrafficCameras/REST/FeedService/

How do I use mappedRequestHeaders to inject username and password into http-client stream?

Comment: See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875927/how-to-set-request-header-in-spring-integration).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do can be achieved by enriching the message flow with the two headers you want and then using `mappedRequestHeaders` to specify that those should be propagated.

Something like this:

```
whatever | modules | transform --script=enrich.groovy | http-client --mappedRequestHeaders=username,password
```

where enrich.groovy adds `username` and `password` as headers in the Spring Integration message.

This does call out for an easy way to pass http headers though, maybe as an option to the module. I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2372 to track this, if you're interested

Comment: Could you please post an example of what enrich.groovy might look like?  I'm tackling a similar issue, and wouldn't mind seeing an example of an enriched message.